# MS Access ToggleButton Picture change

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I was wondering if it is possible to change the picture of a toggle button in Access VBA depending on the state of the toggle button (pressed and not pressed)?

My previous attempt on doing it included a check if the button's value is "true", but it hasn't really produced a valid result.

```
If Me.Toggle4.Value = True Then
    Me.Toggle4.Picture = "IMAGE"
Else
    Me.Toggle4.Picture = "IMAGE"
End If
```

What the code above produces is the button always having the same image.

Comment: "IMAGE" must be full path/filename of an external image. Works for me.

Comment: I did use the full path ("C:\...."), but it does show only the image when the toggle is off (the else statement).

Comment: Can't reproduce issue so can't explain why. As I said, works for me. Except I did not use `.Value = True`, just `Me.Toggle4 Then`.

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't allow me to use that method. Reason: "Invalid use of Null".

Comment: Also, I am using Access2010.

Comment: Ah, I see. That could be the reason. Or, it could be that I have put the whole code in the wrong section. Where did you place it, exactly?

Comment: Toggle4 Click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the code seemed to run properly, except that it was place in the incorrect code section. The whole if-else statement was placed in the `Form_Load()` sub rather than the `Toggle4_OnClick()`. Special thanks to June7 for the help.