# MS Access Toggle Button background

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to totally remove the background color and the border of a toggle button in Access? As shown in the Imgur picture, I'd like to remove the grey-ish background and the border of the button totally so I'd keep the white icon (that list icon) only. Would that even be possible?

[image]

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find (kind of) a solution to this. The solution was to change the following parameters:

```
Use Theme = No; 
BackColor = Form Color; 
Pressed Back Color = Form Color
```

Eventually, it provides an effect very similar to the one that I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is related to your other question at [MS Access ToggleButton Picture change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914489/ms-access-togglebutton-picture-change?noredirect=1#comment82798399_47914489).

Use an Image control with embedded image and this code (note declaration of public variable in header):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public booMenu

Sub timeout(duration_ms As Double)
    Dim Start_Time As Double
    Start_Time = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (Timer - Start_Time) >= duration_ms
End Sub

Private Sub Image5_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    booMenu = Not booMenu
    Me.Menu.Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents
        Me.Menu.Width = Me.Menu.Width + IIf(booMenu, 200, -200)
        Me.Menu.Left = Me.Menu.Left - IIf(booMenu, 200, -200)
        Me.Image5.Left = Me.Image5.Left - IIf(booMenu, 200, -200)
        timeout (0.01)
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until x = 10
    Me.Menu.Visible = booMenu
End Sub
```

Comment: In other words, you say I should remove the Toggle Button and use an image instead?

Comment: Only way I can see to get the effect you describe.